# Unset specific value in an array on mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, unset

I have a table naming related_products,

Where
`products_id` is the main product.

and `related_products_ids` consist of product ids related to the main product.

```
--------------------------------------------
|   products_id   |   related_products_ids |
| -----------------------------------------
|    1            |   2,3                  |
| -----------------------------------------
|    2            |   1,3                  |
| -----------------------------------------
|    3            |   1,2                  |
-------------------------------------------
```

I have checkboxes,

```
<input value="1" type="checkbox" name="rp_product[]" id="in-category1"> Microsoft IntelliMouse Pro 1
<input value="2" type="checkbox" name="rp_product[]" id="in-category2"> Microsoft IntelliMouse Pro 2
<input value="3" type="checkbox" name="rp_product[]" id="in-category3"> Microsoft IntelliMouse Pro 3
```

The checkboxes are generated by php,

```
    <?php
    echo '<div class="categorydiv"><div id="category-all" class="tabs-panel"><ul id="categorychecklist" class="list:category categorychecklist form-no-clear">';
      $rp_sql = "select products_id, products_name from ".TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION." order by products_id";
      $rp_1 = mysql_query($rp_sql);
            while($rp_2 = mysql_fetch_array($rp_1)) {
            echo "<li id=\"category-".$rp_2['products_id']."\" class=\"popular-category\"><label class=\"selectit\"><input value=\"".$rp_2['products_id']."\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"rp_product[]\" id=\"in-category-1\"> ".$rp_2['products_name']."</label></li>";
            }
    mysql_free_result($rp_1);
    echo '</ul></div></div>';
    ?>
```

And i use this code to save the checked checkboxes to the `related_products` table,

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['rp_product']); $i++)
 {
  $check_val1 .= $_POST['rp_product'][$i] .","; //gather data
 }
$check_val = trim($check_val1, ',');  //clean last ,
unset($check_val1); //flush

$related_products = array('products_id' => (int)$products_id,
                        'related_products_ids' => $check_val);

$insert_rp_ids1 = explode(',', $check_val);

    foreach($insert_rp_ids1 as $rp_ids)
    {
    $result_rp = mysql_query("SELECT related_products_ids, products_id FROM ".TABLE_RELATED_PRODUCTS." where products_id = '" . $rp_ids ."'");

     if(mysql_num_rows($result_rp))
     {
       $related_products_value = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_rp);
       $check_dup = explode(',', $related_products_value['related_products_ids']);
        $rp_values = $related_products_value['related_products_ids'] . "," . $products_id;

        $rps_each1 = array('related_products_ids' => $rp_values);
        if(!in_array($products_id, $check_dup)) {
        $wpdb->update( TABLE_RELATED_PRODUCTS, $rps_each1, array( 'products_id' => $rp_ids ));
        }
     }
       else
            {
               $rps_each2 = array('products_id' => $rp_ids, 'related_products_ids' => $products_id);
               $wpdb->insert(TABLE_RELATED_PRODUCTS, $rps_each2);
            }
    }
```

What i want is to `unset` a particular id under `related_products_ids` column when the checkbox previously selected is deselected..

Lets say im editing the post where the id is `2` and where the `related_products_ids` of it is `1,3`.. I deselected the checkbox where the value is `3`(which is on the `related_products_ids`) and after hitting the save button, the value `3` on the `related_products_ids` will be unset so the current value now is `1`. How to do that? I can't think and find a solution for this.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **Normalize** your database. Storing Comma separated values in database is never a good idea.

This is the main difficulty with such unnormalized database we can't manipulate data easily.

You should make parent child tables for storing related products instead of storing them like this way.

Comment: This is the solution i currently know.. can you help me develop a new solution if possible? Thank you.

Comment: @Ken Change your schema so that the `related_product_ids` columns stores just one value (you should change the column name too) so that each row represents one relationship (e.g. 1-2, 1-3 etc). You should consider whether you need to store 1-2 and 2-1 separately (this will depend on your domain logic).